# Selenium Webdriver test works locally but fails on the build server

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my selenium webdriver - ruby test builds locally and identifies all the elements on firefox. However, it fails on the server. Strange thing is that the step it is failing on comes up 4 times in the test. And it passes the first 3 times and fails on the 4th time. How can I troubleshoot this issue? what could be the possible cause of failure?

Comment: Rails?  Go through your config directories (your local and your remote), probably there are different setups defined.  Also you should turn on all verbosity (rake -v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as simple as it sounds, I could resolve this issue by adding some time waits in the test script, especially around the steps which required actions on a child window. Since my test involved lots of child windows, modal windows, flash messages etc., It took me a lot of time to identify the exact step where the script failed.
The server that I was running the test has a headless browser and therefore few actions(pop up window actions) take longer than usual.